# Do loop again when error

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I tried to read everything, but i kind of got stuck on one problem.
By using bigrquery I create queries to Google BigQuery to get data - unfortunately sometimes my query doesn't work because of a time-out.
Q is a SQL-Query and BQ is supposed to store the data downloaded from BigQuery.

Does anybody know how to re-do a loop every time tryCatch gives me an error?

I got this so far:

```
BQ_Foo <- NULL
tryCatch(
{ 
repeat{
  BQ_Foo <- query_exec(Q_foo,"bigquery")
  if(is.list(BQ_Foo) == TRUE)break }
}
,error=function(e){cat("ERROR : Query not loaded!", "\n")}
)
```

EDIT:

I tried my first approach again and this time i received this error message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
>   Operation was aborted by an application callback

Does anybody know how to handle this?

Comment: forgot to explain: if the query doesn't load is.list(BQ_Foo) is FALSE

Comment: Maybe `withRestart` couod be of help (ftom `?tryCatch`)

Comment: I'm still absorbing that. Another article is in [Hadley's Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html).

Comment: cesco, does the answer work for you? If so, please "accept" it (check mark next to the answer), otherwise let us know what doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: hi everyone, sorry for keeping you waiting - i'm trying to implement it into my code now. will give an update asap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Widely based on r2evans answer, here's how to do the same kind of things with `withRestarts`, with some helps from [This blog post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2012/10/error-handling-in-r/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=error-handling-in-r):

```
set.seed(2)
foo <- NULL
operation <- function(x,tries) {
  message(paste("x is",x,"remaining tries",tries))
  withRestarts(
    tryCatch({
      if (runif(1) < x) stop("fail!") else 1
    },
    error=function(e) { invokeRestart("retry")}),
    retry = function() { 
      message("Retrying")
      stopifnot(tries > 0)
      operation(x,tries-1)
    }
  )
}
> operation(0.9,5)
# x is 0.9 remaining tries 5
# Retrying
# x is 0.9 remaining tries 4
# Retrying
# x is 0.9 remaining tries 3
# Retrying
# x is 0.9 remaining tries 2
# Retrying
# x is 0.9 remaining tries 1
[1] 1
```

It's a kind of recursive call, so you can do whatever you want before calling the function again.

You may do it in the tryCatch error handler the same way, the interest to use restarts handlers is to call a specific function, if you had two tryCatch for which you want nearly same handler behavior then you can add a parameter and use the same handler for each try catch, i.e.:

```
testfun <- function(x) {
  withRestarts({
    tryCatch(
      {
        ifelse(runif(1) < 0.5,stop("Error Message"),warning("Warning message"))
      },
      warning=function(e) { invokeRestart("logger", level="warning", message=e ) },
      error=function(e) { invokeRestart("logger", level="error", message=e ) } 
    )
    },
    logger = function(level,message) {
      message(date()," [",level,"]: ",message[['message']])
    }
  )
}
```

Giving:

```
> set.seed(2)
> testfun()
Fri Jul 29 14:15:11 2016 [error]: Error Message
> testfun()
Fri Jul 29 14:15:12 2016 [warning]: Warning message
> testfun()
Fri Jul 29 14:15:13 2016 [warning]: Warning message
> testfun()
Fri Jul 29 14:15:13 2016 [error]: Error Message
```

Main interest here is the factorizing of the logger method and to reduce code duplication.

Comment: well, it kind of works, but it still receive timeouts warnings:  `Fri Jul 29 15:15:53 2016 [error]: Timeout was reached`

Comment: @cesco what is kind of working ? this output seems like my second example which is in no way recursive (the logger function doesn't recall the parent function in anyway) and was just a simplified example of a common handler ... Take some time to really read the answer to get what each example does.

Comment: @Tensibai - you're right, sorry! I am kind of new to it - but i worked myself trough your example and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tensibai, as you said, this produces a recursive call tree. When I tried it, the first time it failed I see a stack of 6 functions; the second time, I see 12, third 18, etc. Is there a way to implement this without going this deep? (I'm not afraid of recursion but have generally preferred to use it when, say, tail-recursion can optimize some behavior of the process, something I believe is not necessarily being done in R.)

Comment: FWIW the impact is nearly null, but if you want to avoid the recursion go for the loop. I do prefer using handlers i' a tryCatch as I find it easier to maintain,  but that's a personal opinion only.

Answer (score 4):

#### Naïve Solution

You might start with a mildly naïve attempt of putting the repeat/while *outside* the `tryCatch`, something like this:

```
set.seed(2)
foo <- NULL
while (is.null(foo)) {
  foo <- tryCatch({
    if (runif(1) < 0.9) stop("fail!") else 1
  },
  error = function(e) { message("err"); NULL; }
  )
}
# err
# err
# err
# err
message("success: ", foo)
# success: 1
```

Unfortunately you introduce the possibility that the loop *will never return*. To protect against this, you can try a counter ...

#### Less-Naïve Solution

```
set.seed(2)
foo <- NULL
max_attempts <- 3
counter <- 0
while (is.null(foo) && counter < max_attempts) {
  counter <- counter + 1
  foo <- tryCatch({
    if (runif(1) < 0.9) stop("fail!") else 1
  },
  error = function(e) { message("err"); NULL; }
  )
}
# err
# err
# err
if (is.null(foo)) message("final failure") else message("success: ", foo)
# final failure
```

Now this is better *for you*, but it may still inadvertently introduce a denial-of-service "attack" on the server. (Consider "why" the query failed: if it is because the server is temporarily inundated, then you are making things worse by clobbering it even for a few limited requests.) Though it slows you down a little, in the case of a busy server, putting in pauses will ease the burden on the server and possibly give you a better chance of a successful query before failing.

#### Better Solution

In network parlance, small TCP packets can cause congestion when repeated retried (see [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) for a quick reference). Using some form of exponential backoff is common, and to guard against two (or more) clients doing exactly same backoff simultaneously, some clients jitter slightly (for example, [`httr::RETRY`](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/R/retry.R)).

```
set.seed(2)
foo <- NULL
max_attempts <- 3
# borrowed from hadley/httr::RETRY
pause_cap <- pause_base <- 1
counter <- 0
while (is.null(foo) && counter < max_attempts) {
  if (counter > 0L) {
    length <- stats::runif(1, max = min(pause_cap, pause_base * (2 ^ counter)))
    message("sleeping ", round(length, 1))
    Sys.sleep(length)
  }
  counter <- counter + 1
  foo <- tryCatch({
    if (runif(1) < 0.9) stop("fail!") else 1
  },
  error = function(e) { message("err"); NULL; }
  )
}
# err
# sleeping 0.7
# err
# sleeping 0.2
if (is.null(foo)) message("final failure") else message("success: ", foo)
# success: 1
```

#### Wrap-Up

Somewhat sloppy code, but I hope you get the point. Putting loops on network queries without some form of self-limit can very easily escalate into an inadvertent DOS.

Comment: I don't how this answer the OP problem

Comment: The OP asked *"how to re-do a loop every time tryCatch gives me an error"*. This provides a method to do a loop while there is an error. Am I missing something?

Comment: No ok, got it, kind of complex approach IMHO, I'm would be more in favor of a handler to restart the tryCatch (taking care of a timeout in this handler).

Comment: You're probably right. Since I'm not as familiar with using `withRestarts`, it's not my first go-to solution (in R). Perhaps you can provide an example that has iteration-limits and sleeps?

Comment: Well, I'll see if I find time to write it properly. The same precautions have to be used, but with bigrquery which is an asynchonous system there's less need as you're just submitting a job and then polling regularly to see if it has completed. I.e: There's few chances to DOS the target here. But I fully agree a number of retry must be enforced, probably with the `test` parameter of the handlers (I ususally don't retry the exact same code, so I've test to do before to ensure it's clear enought). [Better explained than I could do](http://www.r-bloggers.com/error-handling-in-r/)

Comment: unfortunately r2evans code crashes my R with an infinite loop. I'll try to check if i might have implemented it wrong, but the withRestarts method sounds promising - i'll try to research that, even tough it seems quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your ideas i created this code, which seems to work - i just need to stresstest it.

```
QFoo <- paste0('SQL Code', dateBQ, ' ')
BQFoo <- NULL
testfun <- function(QFoo) {
    withRestarts({
        tryCatch({
            query_exec(QFoo, "bigquery")
        },
        warning = function(e) { invokeRestart("logger", level="warning", message = e) },
        error = function(e) { invokeRestart("logger", level="error", message = e) })
    },
    logger = function(level, message) {
        message(date(), " [", level, "]: ", message[['message']])
    })
}
testfun(QFoo)
```

Comment: There's no chance this would retry, there's no callback to the query function here, my second example is a demonstration of use, not an attempt to answer your problem. first example is more likely to help you, with the `query_exec` instead of the `if (runif...` block. And answers are supposed to answer the question, SO is not a forum, if you have things to add, edit your question and then eventually ping users with @name .

Comment: You're giving me the feeling you did stop reading my comment after first dot. Take a step back, and read the answer again, fully,  including the text between the code blocks.